# Add random element to files in private so they can't be guessed

Tags: files

I want to add a random element to files in the /private/ directory so filenames cannot be guessed. In other words, when a file is uploaded by the admin I want the URL to download the file to be:

/system/files/RANDOM/original_filename.pdf

This is because users need access to all of the content type that contains the file, but only have access to a file associated if there is an entity reference link to their user profile on the node.

Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The better way is to secure the files properly - security through obscurity is always a pointless act

Comment: you can simply check the refferences and unset file fields in preprocess functions